# How to use google analytics data to create a dynamic recommendation engine

Tags: machine-learning, google-analytics, recommendation-engine

I am building a recommendation engine and I want that more dynamic. I wanna use google analytic data along with data I have to give users a good recommendation by capturing user's details automatically. is there any particular method for doing that or to blend both google analytic data and local data to work my recommendation engine more dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the search terms in the engine inside your site (if they are defined in the URL, i.e. in querystring, you can specify the parameter and collect them in the dedicated report, otherwise if they are inside the path you can use a filter and extract them).

You can then add them manually or dynamically to your database to offer better search results.